# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(Ljava/util/List;Lcom/mongodb/MongoCredential;Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientOptions;)V]

Tags: java, mongodb

While trying to access mongodb from my QA enviornment its showing the below error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init> (Ljava/util/List;Lcom/mongodb/MongoCredential;Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientOptions;)V]
```

The same is working from my local env. The mongo driver im using in 3.6.2 and java version is 1.8.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

When I updated to version 3.8.0, it worked. My problem occurred because I've updated the Spring Data Mongo and forgot to update the Mongo Driver.