# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientURI

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am very new to scala spark and Mongo. while trying to load some data to MongoDB by spark with the following code.

```
import com.mongodb.spark.config.WriteConfig
import com.mongodb.spark.toDocumentRDDFunctions
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.bson.Document

object MongoTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName(this.getClass.getSimpleName)
      .getOrCreate()

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(this.getClass.getSimpleName).set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val documents = sc.parallelize((1 to 10).map(i => Document.parse(s"{test: $i}")))
    documents.saveToMongoDB(WriteConfig(Map("spark.mongodb.output.uri" -> "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sampledb.testMongo")))
  }
}
```

The error occurs and my spark submit fails with following error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientURI;)V
        at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:328)
        at com.mongodb.spark.connection.DefaultMongoClientFactory.create(DefaultMongoClientFactory.scala:43)
        at com.mongodb.spark.connection.MongoClientCache.acquire(MongoClientCache.scala:55)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.acquireClient(MongoConnector.scala:239)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withMongoClientDo(MongoConnector.scala:152)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withDatabaseDo(MongoConnector.scala:171)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withCollectionDo(MongoConnector.scala:184)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1.apply(MongoSpark.scala:116)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1.apply(MongoSpark.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:403)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1405)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:409)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I use Spark version 2.4.0 and Scala version 2.11.12. Any idea where I am wrong.?

Comment: What is your MongoDB and Mongo Driver version you are using? Did you pass the mongo driver to the spark-shell or submit?

Comment: I use MongoDB server version: 4.2.5. Mongo driver is passed to the spark-submit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782145/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-mongodb-mongoclient-initljava-util-listlcom

Comment: @chris you are probably not using the right version of the driver as per Spark 2.4.5 and MongoDB 4.2.5. Specify your driver version since I couldn't find the driver for Spark 2.4.5 [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/release-notes/)